# Multiple run lint-staged when use with husky

Tags: javascript, configuration, husky, lint-staged

When I use `npx lint-staged` in the terminal everything looks ok.

For example:

```
PS E:\Projects\sample-project> git status
On branch main
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git restore --staged <file>..." to unstage)
        new file:   .husky/commit-msg
        new file:   .husky/pre-commit
        new file:   .lintstagedrc.json
        modified:   .prettierrc
        new file:   commitlint.config.js
        modified:   nx.json
        modified:   package-lock.json
        modified:   package.json

PS E:\Projects\sample-project> npx lint-staged
√ Preparing lint-staged...
√ Running tasks for staged files...
√ Applying modifications from tasks...
√ Cleaning up temporary files...
PS E:\Projects\sample-project>
```

but when my husky `pre-commit` hook runs the same command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npx lint-staged
```

In the terminal I receive something like this:

```
PS E:\Projects\sample-project> git commit -m"ci(core): configure project
>> 
>> edit prettier
>> add husky, commit-lint, lint-staged"
■ Preparing lint-staged...
■ Preparing lint-staged...
■ Running tasks for staged files...
■ Preparing lint-staged...
■ Running tasks for staged files...
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Preparing lint-staged...
■ Running tasks for staged files...
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
- Preparing lint-staged...
■ Running tasks for staged files...
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
\ Preparing lint-staged...
■ Running tasks for staged files...
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
| Preparing lint-staged...
■ Running tasks for staged files...
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
■ Running tasks for staged files...
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
| Running tasks for staged files...
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  ■ .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  | .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    ■ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    ■ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    ■ *.js — 1 file
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    | *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    ■ *.js — 1 file
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    | *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    | *.js — 1 file
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    > *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    | *.js — 1 file
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    > *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    > *.js — 1 file
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    > *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
      ■ prettier --write
    > *.js — 1 file
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    > *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
      ■ prettier --write
    > *.js — 1 file
      ■ eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    > *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
      | prettier --write
    > *.js — 1 file
      ■ eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    > *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
      | prettier --write
    > *.js — 1 file
      | eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    > *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
      / prettier --write
    > *.js — 1 file
      / eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    > *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
      - prettier --write
    > *.js — 1 file
      - eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    > *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
      \ prettier --write
    > *.js — 1 file
      \ eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    > *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
      | prettier --write
    > *.js — 1 file
      | eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    > *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
      √ prettier --write
    > *.js — 1 file
      | eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    √ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    > *.js — 1 file
      | eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    √ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    > *.js — 1 file
      / eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    √ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    > *.js — 1 file
      - eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    √ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    > *.js — 1 file
      \ eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    √ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    > *.js — 1 file
      | eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    √ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    > *.js — 1 file
      / eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    √ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    > *.js — 1 file
      - eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    √ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    > *.js — 1 file
      \ eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    √ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    > *.js — 1 file
      | eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    √ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    > *.js — 1 file
      / eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    √ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    > *.js — 1 file
      - eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    √ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    > *.js — 1 file
      \ eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    √ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    > *.js — 1 file
      √ eslint --fix
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  > .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
    √ *.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html} — 1 file
    √ *.js — 1 file
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
> Running tasks for staged files...
  √ .lintstagedrc.json — 8 files
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
√ Running tasks for staged files...
■ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
√ Running tasks for staged files...
\ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
√ Running tasks for staged files...
| Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
√ Running tasks for staged files...
√ Applying modifications from tasks...
■ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
√ Running tasks for staged files...
√ Applying modifications from tasks...
| Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
√ Running tasks for staged files...
√ Applying modifications from tasks...
/ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
√ Running tasks for staged files...
√ Applying modifications from tasks...
√ Cleaning up temporary files...
√ Preparing lint-staged...
√ Running tasks for staged files...
√ Applying modifications from tasks...
√ Cleaning up temporary files...
lint commit
[main 3110d3d] ci(core): configure project
 8 files changed, 10673 insertions(+), 3421 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 .husky/commit-msg
 create mode 100644 .husky/pre-commit
 create mode 100644 .lintstagedrc.json
 create mode 100644 commitlint.config.js
PS E:\Projects\sample-project>
```

Did someone know how I can fix this?

.lintstagedrd.json

```json
{
  "*.{js,ts,css,scss,md,html}": "prettier --write",
  "*.js": "eslint --fix"
}
```

Answer (score 7):

There is a [draft PR](https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged/pull/1163) in lint-staged that will fix this.  In the meantime, this [workaround](https://github.com/typicode/husky/issues/968#issuecomment-1176848345) worked for me:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
. "$(dirname -- "$0")/_/husky.sh"

exec >/dev/tty 2>&1

npx lint-staged
```

https://github.com/okonet/lint-staged/issues/1164#issuecomment-1177561594

Comment: I also have a workaround. In my case, I created a custom script to run logger with spinner to husky. Example command `node tools/looger.js command="lint-staged" run="npx lint-staged -q"`

Comment: Unfortunately this workaround does not work in all environments as /dev/tty can be "undefined" (so you get error that no such device or address was found)... Hopefully they will fix it soon

Comment: The workaround does not work on windows ("/dev/tty: No such device or address"). Do I understand correctly, that the multiple outputs are due to not being able to update a spinner and not meaning it runs multiple times?